# How do I use pytest on a function that always calls sys.exit()?

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, pytest

First, my Python code:

```
def terminate(code, message):
    if code in exit_codes:
        if not isinstance(message, type(None)) and not message == '':
            sys.stderr.write(message)
        sys.exit(exit_codes[code])
    else:
        error = 'ERROR: a termination request was received with an invalid exit code.\n'
        error += 'This is mostly likely a developer/application problem.\n'
        terminate('BAD_CODE', error)
```

I have a globally defined dictionary of exit code strings corresponding to numbers that are given to `sys.exit()`. If the `code` argument is a valid, exit code, `sys.exit()` is called with that code's integer value as an argument. Otherwise, `terminate()` is recursively called with the `BAD_CODE` dictionary entry that is guaranteed to exist, which then ends up calling `sys.exit()`.

Either way, `sys.exit()` ends up being called, and so the Exception type is SystemExit. How do I write a unit test for pytest so that I am not only checking that SystemExit was in fact raised, but that the integer value sent to `sys.exit()` is what it should be?

I've gotten as far as the typical `with raises(SystemExit) as exc_info:` context manager line, but I'm stuck on the integer value checking part.

Comment: You mock `sys.exit`: `@mock.patch('sys.exit')`.

Comment: Oh neat! If mock is something specific to pytest, I just started building my first unit test system so it make sense that I wouldn't know everything about the API. If it's a general Python thing, I just feel stupid. :P

Thanks!

Comment: The `mock` module is part of the `unittest` package in Python 3 and an independent package that has to be installed separately on Python 2.

Comment: @KlausD. after running `pip install mock` to install for Python2 I get `ImportError: No module named mock.` Additionally, the output of the `pip install` only references the /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages directory, but nothing about Python2.7. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The it was ran for Python 3 which has `mock` built-in. You might also want to use a virtual environment instead of installing your packages system-wide:http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/